# How do you partition an array into 2 parts such that the two parts have equal average?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

How do you partition an array into 2 parts such that the two parts have equal average? Each partition may contain elements that are non-contiguous in the array.
The only algorithm I can think of is exponential can we do better?

Comment: Be honest, is this a homework question?

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work? Have you got some test cases with example input and output?

Comment: this sounds more like an interview question, not an easy one at that

Comment: The only algorithm I can think of is exponential can we do better?

Comment: This question is especially skimpy on details. Let's start with the basics, for example *is it guaranteed* that there is such a partition? If it's a verbatim interview question and you do not immediately ask for more information I 'd say you failed the question.

Comment: What *is* the algorithm that you can think of?

Comment: brute force testing all subsets would calculate a solution if there is one - but this is O(2**N)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can reduce this problem to the [sum-subset problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) - also [cached here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3afYcePS8IwvIJ%3aen.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).  Here's the idea.

Let `A` be the array. Compute `S = A[0] + ... + A[N-1]`, where `N` is the length of `A`. For `k` from `1` to `N-1`, let `T_k = S * k / N`. If `T_k` is an integer, then find a subset of `A` of size `k` that sums to `T_k`. If you can do this, then you're done. If you cannot do this for any `k`, then no such partitioning exists.

---

Here's the math behind this approach. Suppose there is a partitioning of `A` such that the two parts have the same average, says `X` of size `x` and `Y` of size `y` are the partitions, where `x+y = N`. Then you must have

```
sum(X)/x = sum(Y)/y = (sum(A)-sum(X)) / (N-x)
```

so a bit of algebra gives

```
sum(X) = sum(A) * x / N
```

Since the array contains integers, the left hand side is an integer, so the right hand side must be as well. This motivates the constraint that `T_k = S * k / N` must be an integer. The only remaining part is to realize `T_k` as the sum of a subset of size `k`.

Comment: after a bit of thinking i still don't see how your proof reduces subset-sum to OP's problem.

Comment: i mean, you essencially proved that having answer to subset sum one can answer OP's problem, not the other way around.

Comment: @soulcheck I'm still pondering whether they are truly equivalent. I believe the answer comes down to [this question I just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916539/sum-subset-with-a-fixed-subset-size).

Comment: @PengOne I am confused whether we can use sum-subset problem to find the set of size k which sums to T_k. What if there are multiple sets of different size that sums to T_k and one such set is of size k. Is there a way we can tweak the sum_subset problem to find if there exists a set of size k?

Comment: @PengOne Is there a solution approach for this question? I wrote a code following this approach but its churning the wrong output. My code: https://ideone.com/HadH3V